# Is there is a way to override scale_colour_manual name

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

My code is

```
myColors <- brewer.pal(5,"Set1")
names(myColors) <- levels(software_length$type)
colScale <- scale_colour_manual(values = myColors,name="Software")
```

In ggplot I used this defined manual color colScale , like

```
 ggplot(data, aes(efficiency)) + theme_gray() + colScale
```

but I would like to change the name from Software to type , I tried to use 
`scale_color_discrete(name="type")` but this override the colors and gives me totally different colors 
It will give this warning;

> Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for
>   'colour', which will replace the existing scale.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to redefine your custom scale as a function:

```
myColors <- brewer.pal(5,"Set1")
names(myColors) <- levels(software_length$type)

my_col_scale <- function(name = "Software", ...) {
    scale_colour_manual(values = myColors, name = name, ...))
}
```

This way the default name will be `"Software"`, but you can adjust that (or any other `scale_colour_manual` settings) in the normal way.

```
ggplot(data, aes(efficiency)) + 
  theme_gray() +
  my_col_scale(name = "type")
```

You may also be interested in `scale_color_brewer`... your scale is essentially `scale_color_brewer(palette = 1, name = "Software")`, but it will only work if there are 5 levels (whereas `scale_color_brewer` will be flexible in the number of levels).

Two examples using `scale_color_brewer`:

```
# the `cut` column has 5 levels
ggplot(head(diamonds, 200), aes(x = carat, y = price, color = cut)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = 1)

# the `clarity` column has 7 levels
# scale_color_brewer makes the change automatically
ggplot(head(diamonds, 200), aes(x = carat, y = price, color = clarity)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = 1)
```

Comment: you mean instead of using scale_colour_manual  , use cale_color_brewer ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: something like this;   myColors <- brewer.pal("Set1")
names(myColors) <- levels(software_length$type)

my_col_scale <- function(name = "Software", ...) {
    scale_color_brewer(values = myColors, name = name, ...))
}     # and this will be suitable for levels more than 5?

Comment: If you use `scale_color_brewer` then you don't need to worry about `brewer.pal` and `names(myColors)` --- that will all be taken care of automatically. Literally, just do `your_ggplot + scale_color_brewer(palette = 1)` and it will work with variable numbers of levels - up to the maximum number for that palette. See edits.

Answer (score 2):

You can update name for the `colScale` using argument `name`

```
colScale$name<-"type"
```

If you don't want to change it globally then save it with different name and then update

```
colScale2<-colScale
colScale2$name<-"type"
```